# Add an Item in the availabe templates in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: c++, visual-studio, templates, visual-studio-2013

How do I add a new Template-type in the tree view of Visual Studio 2013 available templates?

If one clicks on New Project, on the right hand side pane of the next window which opens, is a list of the available templates offered by Visual Studio, such as those categorized under Visual C#, Visual C++ etc.

I wish to add a similar template in the tree view. Is there a way to achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Private templates go in (but adjust the `C:\Users\{{username}}` as necessary):

```
C:\Users\{{username}}\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Templates\ProjectTemplates\Visual C++ Project\
```

Public templates go subdirectories of:

```
{{VisualStudioInstallationDirectory}}\Common7\IDE\ProjectTemplates\{{Language}}
```

See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y3kkate1.aspx) for more details.