# Where do downloaded Visual Studio Item Templates (samples) from the Visual Studio Online Gallery get saved

Tags: c#, visual-studio, templates, visual-studio-2013

I recently downloaded and installed an item template by searching online in the New Item dialog in Visual Studio 2013.  The template is not listed in a specific category when using the New Item dialog now.  I would like to move it into the "Code" category.  I have found all the installed templates in my `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\ItemTemplates` directory, but the one I downloaded doesn't seem to be in there.  It is also not in my `C:\Users\<MyUsername>\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Templates\ItemTemplates` directory.

Where are templates saved when you download them from the online gallery?

Comment: Do you mean a sample? Samples are actually special VSIX extensions, whose files will be found at `%LOCALAPPDATA%\Microsoft\VisualStudio\12.0\Extensions`. They're tricky to mess with manually, though -- there's several layers of caches. (You'll need to remove the cache file and probably run `devenv /installvstemplates` too, and even that may not be enough.)

Comment: @Cameron - I found the sample exactly where you said it would be.  I was able to edit the .zip file there to modify the category where the template is listed in the New Item dialog.  Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Add an Item in the availabe templates in Visual Studio 2013](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28018675/add-an-item-in-the-availabe-templates-in-visual-studio-2013)

Comment: @AdrianHHH: That question's about templates, whereas this one is about samples (despite the similarity in resulting effects, they're quite different internally).

Comment: @AdrianHHH - that question has nothing to do with what I am asking here.  That answer is specific to private templates.  However, the template I am dealing with is a sample downloaded from the Visual Studio Online Gallery and is stored in a different place.

Comment: OK Brian. The question does not use the word "sample" but it does use the word "template" several times and it asks "Where are templates saved ...". Perhaps you could clarify the question to make it clear what you are asking.