# Visual Studio: Make Templates Globally Accessible

Tags: c#, visual-studio, templates, visual-studio-2013

I created a Visual C# template using the Export Templates option in Visual Studio 2013 Express. Copying the template to ***C:\Users\user\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Templates\ProjectTemplates\Visual C#*** works like a charm. 
However, I would like to make the template accessible to all users using the server. The most obvious option would be to copy the template to ***C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\ProjectTemplates\Visual C#\1031*** but this did not work. I tried various language names (CSharp, Visual CSharp, C#,...) and various locales (mainly 1031 and 1033, as the locale of the server is currently set to German (Switzerland)). 
I also tried running the *wbexpress.exe /installvstemplates* command to no avail (see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y3kkate1%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).
Am I missing something?

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28018675/add-an-item-in-the-availabe-templates-in-visual-studio-2013 and the MSDN page linked in the answer.

Comment: This is exactly what I did. Private templates work, public templates don't.